# Test if array has value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array that I fetched from git HUB api,

```
[{
 id: 362784382,
 imageURL: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CRISTIAN-MULLER/BookShelf-Backend/main/Tela.png",
 name: "BookShelf Backend" ,
 ownerName: "CRISTIAN-MULLER",
 topics: ["javascript","reactjs"]
},
{
  id: 362784383,
  imageURL: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CRISTIAN-MULLER/BookShelf- 
  Backend/main/Tela.png",
  name: "BookShelf" ,
  ownerName: "CRISTIAN-MULLER",
  topics: ["other tag","react"]

}

]
```

This data has tags with languages that I used in My projects,

In another part of my code i have a function that iterates trough this array and returns a array of tags with unique names.

```
const topicsWithoutDuplicates = [...new Set(topics.flat())].map((elem) => ({
    id: elem,
    title: elem,
  }));
```

I render for each element a button im My portfolio page, and I need to when i click a button , iterate all data and return only the projects that has the topic matching the button ID,

I'm trying to construct a function that do this, but I'm stuck, "selected" has an array of strings with the buttons pressed ["javascript", "react", ....],

I know that includes Method receives only strings as arguments and thats way this is not working, so I need to get the "selected" array and for each, item iterate over the received data from github and return only the elements that has in topics the same name that I have in selected array.

so basicaly i need to iterate an array over another array comparing each element.

```
  const filteredData = userData.filter((item) =>
      item.topics.map((topic) =>
        topic.includes(selected)
      )
    );
```

How can I do that?, I'm not thinking anymore.

Comment: "*I have a array that I fetched from git HUB api*" This "*array*" is not valid in any JavaScript spec I'm aware of; are you sure you don't have an object...? This fact would materially affect what answers you will get.

Comment: Or maybe an array of objects? `[ {id: ... }, {id: ...}]`

Comment: Hei, yes I know, I just copy and paste some data, I will edit the question with the right data.

Comment: The data looks to me to be like JSON, perhaps?  In any event, if you know the format, please specify it, see also comment by esqew above.

Comment: @JosephDoggie If it was JSON, the keys would need to be encapsulated as strings within quotes, at the very least.

Comment: `userData.filter(item => item.topics.includes(selected))`

Comment: Why has this been closed already? The OP said they were going to fix the problem and hasn't had a chance to do so yet.

Comment: @computercarguy As the close reason indicates it is, at this very moment, lacking the necessary detail to provide any adequate answer. Once the edits are made it's automatically dropped into a queue for reopening. This is entirely intended by design...

Comment: I'va tried this , userData.filter(item => item.topics.includes(selected)), but "selected" is an array, so I can't use includes with it.

Comment: @esqew, except for the fact that I can read around the obvious mistypes and understand the actual problem the OP is having and being so quick on the draw to immediately close it prevents me from writing an answer, not to mention it makes more work for people to reopen the question.

Comment: the received data is an array of objects.

Comment: I don't know where I'm wrong in this posted question, what kind of information is missing? I'm from Brazil , so my english is not that great, I'm working on it.

Comment: @CristianMüller, you now have to wait for the question to go through the Reopen Queue, which is at 309. I've flagged this for moderator review, due to that queue is moving so slowly, so hopefully you don't have to wait a day or more for it to get reopened.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait, and continue to try another things.

Comment: @CristianMüller, my flag was declined, so it's not going to be reopened any time soon.

Comment: Hey guys and Girls, I figured out, just take a break , get a coffe and solved the problem, turns out my logic was backwards, I leave here the code after some thinking for future refrence, 
const filteredData = [
        ...new Set(
          selected
            .map((topic) => {
              const temp = userData.filter((item) => {
                return item.topics.includes(topic);
              });
              return temp;
            })
            .flat()
        ),
      ];

Comment: @CristianMüller, well, it's finally been reopened. I'd suggest putting your fix in an answer and mark it as accepted (which will likely take a couple days before you can do that, too). Otherwise, this question might get closed again or deleted.